# Reversed Linked List only prints as one node

Tags: java, linked-list

I was coding on gfg practice to test whether a linked list is a palindrome, and after I reversed the linked list, it showed only one node.

This is the code below (the linked list passed is 1->2->1) :-

```
class Solution
{
    //Function to check whether the list is palindrome.
    boolean isPalindrome(Node head) 
    {
        Node temp=head;
        Node reversed= reverseList(temp);
        Node cur = head;
        
        while(cur!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(cur.data+"    inloop");
            cur=cur.next;
        }
         
        return true;
    } 

    Node reverseList(Node node)
    {        
        Node prev = null;
        Node current = node;
        Node next = null;
        while (current != null) {
            next = current.next;
            current.next = prev;
            prev = current;
            current = next;
        }
        node = prev;
        return node; 
    }
}
```

The output of this code is ( the linked list passed is 1->2->1) : -

```
1    inloop
```

But if I comment out the `Node reversed = reverseList(temp);` line, the output is as expected: -

```
1    inloop
2    inloop
1    inloop
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I would like you to (1) post a [mre] so that I can see in my debugger what happens (2) indent your code properly so I can read it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the list is reversed, the previous head of the list has become the tail. Concretely, after that reversal, `head` references the tail of the now reversed list. A tail has (by definition) a `next` member that is `null`, and so your `while` loop will only iterate once.

Realise that when you reverse the list, you don't have the original order anymore: all `next` members have lost their original value and now (only) have a reference that reflects the reversed order.

You have a few options to do it right:

1. Have your `reverse` method create a **new** list, so that caller will then have both the original and the reversed list. This will allow you to iterate both lists in tandem and compare the node values as intended
2. Create an array from the list. Now check whether the array is a palindrome.
3. The above options need O(n) extra space. You can solve this without O(n)
   auxiliary space: only reverse **half** of the list. Here you don't need to create new nodes, but by only reversing half of the list, you can traverse the reversed part and the non-reversed part in tandem and make value comparisons